# Modify SKU Syntax in Magneto Using Automatic Simple Products Generator

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable

I am working in Magento and I am using an extension called wp_simple_products_generator. Now I want to change the syntax of SKU of my products to "sku-colorcode". Supposing if SKU is DM45 and my black color code is '1' then I would like my SKU format to show like this 'DM45-1'. How can I change the color code in this format ... Thanks

Here is the Automatic Code by Wp_Simple_Products_Generator:

private function _getSimpleProductPrefixes($combination)
    {
        $skuPrefixParts = $namePrefixParts = array();
        $configurableAttributes = $this->_configurableAttributes;
        foreach ($combination as $attrCode => $value) {
            // --- generate Name of the Simple Product ---
            $prefix = $configurableAttributes[$attrCode]['label'] . ' ' . $configurableAttributes[$attrCode]['values'][$value];
            $namePrefixParts[] = $prefix;
           // $skuPrefixParts[] = str_replace(' ', '-', $prefix);
           $prefix_sku = substr($configurableAttributes[$attrCode]['values'][$value],0,10); 
           $skuPrefixParts[] = str_replace(' ', '-', $prefix_sku );

```
    }
    $skuPrefix = '-' . implode('-', $skuPrefixParts);
    $namePrefix = ' - ' . implode(' - ', $namePrefixParts);

    return array($skuPrefix, $namePrefix);
}
```

Comment: you really need to post some example code in order to receive proper help

Comment: thankyou for you reply.